# Avoiding insertion of duplicate rows where "duplicate" is non-trivial

Tags: sql

My db contains a table that is designed like:

```
| A | B | date | C | D | E |
```

Given a temp table with the same design, I desire to insert its contents into the permanent table in my db. However, I only want to insert the rows in temp that differ from the most recent row where 
temp.A = perm.A and temp.B = perm.B. The recency of the rows is determined by the date column.

For example, given a perm table that looks like:

```
| "Joe" | "Consultant" | 8/21/2014 | 40 | 72 | 54 |

| "Joe" | "Consultant" | 8/16/2014 | 25 | 72 | 30 |
```

then a temp table row that looks like:

```
| "Joe" | "Consultant" | 8/25/2014 | 40 | 72 | 54 |
```

should not get inserted, but

```
| "Joe" | "Consultant" | 8/25/2014 | 25 | 72 | 30 |
```

should.

Of course, any row with a previously non-existent A or B column entries should also be inserted.

I have messed around with a couple ways to do this (including iteration), but I am not sure what the correct way to go about this is? I am a novice SQL dev so any advice would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Define `SQL`... MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: It might be more appropriate (simpler) to do the logic in the program that is storing the data.  Or, you could create a recent_records table:  If a new record is already in the table, discard the new record, otherwise move an old row from the recent records_table to the permanent destination table and insert the new row.   It's like a staging table.   But that's a lot of messy work.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand why the two rows you want to insert, in the example, have the same date, it's that an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
insert into perm (a,b,c,d,e,f)
select
t.*
from
temp t left outer join
(
select
p.*
from
perm p inner join
(
select a, b, max(c) as max_c
from perm
group by a,b) mx on
p.a = mx.a and
p.b = mx.b and
p.c = max_c
  ) p on
t.a = p.a and
t.b = p.b and
t.c > p.c and
t.d = p.d and
t.e = p.e and
t.f = p.f
where
    p.a is null
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85444/12/1)

Comment: Thanks Beth! I ended up doing it slightly differently but this got me 90% of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS allows this an INSERT... SELECT ... where the table being inserted is referenced within the SELECT part, you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO PERM
select * FROM TEMP T
where NOT EXISTS 
(select *
 from PERM P
 WHERE P.A=T.A and P.B=T.B and P.C=T.C and P.D=T.D and P.E=T.E
)
```

If your DBMS does not allow the reference, you could insert into "TEMP2", and then insert everything from there into PERM